# AEM/CQ - javax.xml.namespace can't resolve OSGI dependency

Tags: java, maven, osgi, aem

I'm using AEM 6.2 and I'm currently implementing WebService.
I included all dependency jars in OSGI bundle which I created externally and all dependency issue got resolved except one:

> **javax.xml.namespace,version=[1.0,2) -- Cannot be resolved**

When I checked in the maven using depfinder tool, it showed me as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.sling.fragment.ws</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

However, in my other custom project, the javax.xml.namespace is showing resolved state.

I'm stuck in this situation and any pointers will be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Jineet

Comment: Check if the other bundle also has the version specific import. If it is then try to find out where it's coming from.

Comment: Thanks for your response @11thdimension, the other bundle which shows resolved is as below:
javax.xml.namespace,version=0.0.0.fragment_xml from org.apache.felix.framework (0)

Comment: Can you override the import version in the second bundle?

Comment: I don't know how to do that @11thdimension
Can you please guide me?
Thanks, Jineet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely at the output of the "Package Dependency" tool you will see that the *Maven* dependency has the version `1.0.2`. The *exported* version of this package on the other hand is `0.0.0.fragment_xml`.

[image: Package Dependency Tool java.xml.namespace exported version]

I do not know why that is but this means you need to use a little workaround to resolve your bundles against this version.

What you basically have to do is to update your `MANIFEST.MF` and change the imported version from `1.0.2` to `0.0.0.fragment_xml`.

We are using Maven and the `maven-bundle-plugin` plugin to achieve this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Import-Package>
                javax.xml.namespace;version="0.0.0.fragment_xml",
                *
            </Import-Package>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are 58 artifacts in maven central that export javax.xml.namespace, with versions matching `[1.0,2)`. A safe choice might be the wrapped javaxp-api from servicemix:

Gradle:

`'org.apache.servicemix.specs:org.apache.servicemix.specs.jaxp-api-1.4:2.8.0'`

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.specs.jaxp-api-1.4</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I Added this dependency, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.